# Add the custom Action to Interface Builder (right click)

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, action

The question is very easy: how to add one more/two/... actions there?

[image: I want to add my action there]

PS.: I Googled a lot, but haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A menu item has one action. If you want more actions you have to create an action which calls the other actions. Some controls have multiple actions, like NSTableView which has an action and a doubleAction.

Comment: Emm... Well, basically that doesn't answers. 
What I needed is how to make my actions appear there? How to write the code inself (IBInspectible or whatever...)

Comment: Do  you want to see the sent actions or the recieved actions? What you see is how the sent action is connected. if you want a different action you have to connect to a different action.

Comment: As shown on attached image, I want 'Sent Actions'. 'Received actions' is not an issues because, as you can see, onStateChange is a custom thing.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that.